# How do I make a proper read-only PyGTK text entry?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to make a widget that holds a short text output that the user should be able to copy, but not change. This is what I've come up with:

```
entry = gtk.Entry()
entry.set_property("editable", False)
entry.unset_flags(gtk.CAN_FOCUS)
```

It works, but the entry still looks like it's editable, and that looks bad from the user perspective. 
I tried `entry.set_sensitive(False)` instead, but this both prevents copying, and makes it look completely disabled.

I would like to know how to make a proper read-only text entry, that's grayed out but still active.

Edit: [Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ReadOnlyComboBoxByClaudio/ReadOnlyComboBox1.gif) an image of what I'm talking about, although not GTK (and I'm working in a GNOME environment).

Edit 2: It's starting to look like there's no right way to do this with GTK, if someone can confirm this I'll mark the question solved.

Comment: If you don't get any info here, you could try posting on the PyGTK list. And if you get an answer from them, and if you feel like it, you could post the answer here :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `Label` that is selectable and in wrap mode (if the text was more than one line)

```
label = gtk.Label('multi line text')
label.set_selectable(True)
label.set_line_wrap_mode(True)
```

Comment: And also set `label.set_can_focus(False)` if you don't want the cursor to be visible.

Comment: This is how I'm going to do it, and wrap the label in a gtk.Frame. This give the result I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: what if I need the contents of the insensitive entry to change with another sensitive entry as with using `entry2.set_buffer ( entry1.get_buffer )` ... this is not applicable by labels, is it?!

Comment: @ophidion No, Labels are not editable, so having a buffer is meaningless. If you want to programmatically change them at once, define a function to do it, or override `set_label` method...

Answer (score 2):

I usually turn off the bevelled frame, so that it looks more like a label but is still selectable.

[image: GTKEntry without frame].

(In the picture, there's a box on the right of the equals sign. It's hard to see here, but in my program there's always text in it, so it's quite clear.)

I do this in Glade, but the method is [GTKEntry.set_has_frame()](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkentry.html#method-gtkentry--set-has-frame).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I might use that, but it's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @spektre - so you're thinking more about background colour than relief style? You know, I'm sure I've done something like this before too...

Comment: Precisely, I've linked to an image in the original post explaining what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

To make it gray, try `entry.`[`modify_text()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--modify-text).

Comment: This is also a workaround, but it won't respect color themes. If the user has a color theme with dark background and light text, this would look worse than an unmodified text entry.

Comment: You can get the user's theme color using [`gtk.Style.lookup_color()`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkstyle.html#method-gtkstyle--lookup-color).